# gitlab api accept merge request fails

Tags: api, curl, merge, gitlab

I have created a shell script to create and accept a merge request.

The first action (creating) is working fine, but the second action (accepting) fails.

This is my code:

```
curl -X PUT -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: abc123" -d id=86 -d merge_request_id=323 https://gitlab/api/v3/projects/86/merge_requests/323/merge
```

API feedback:

```
{"message":"404 Not found"}
```

GitLab API documentation on merge requests:
https://gitlab.com/help/api/merge_requests.md#accept-mr

Answer (score 1):

## If you are using GitLab API v4

In this API version you should use `iid`, in the MR API calls, so the same id which you see in the web UI MR URL.

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/v3_to_v4.html :

> API uses merge request `IID`s (internal ID, as in the web UI) rather
>   than `ID`s. This affects the merge requests, award emoji, todos, and
>   time tracking APIs.

## If you are using GitLab API v3

Use the globally unique internal id of the MR, **NOT** its local id.

So if you have a web UI URL of the MR you want to accept, like this:

```
https://gitlab.domain.com/group/project/merge_requests/11/commits
                                                       ^^--- ..then *DON'T* use this id!
```

Instead if you create the MR with the API (or [get a list of them in a project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests)) and see its JSON:

```
{
  "id": 16393, # <--- ...then USE THIS id...
  "iid": 11,
  "project_id": 1162,
  "title": "MR title...",
  (...)
}
```

...in your MR accept request:

```
 curl -X PUT https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/projects/1162/merge_requests/16393/merge
 #                            the globally unique internal id of the MR ---^^^^^
```

---

(In my opinion this is kind of misleading, because as of March 2017 [the GitLab API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) call the global one `iid` (internal id)...)

Answer (score -1):

Shortly after my previous post I have found out that the URL is incorrect.

The structure is not kept the same across the API.

The request that works is:
https://gitlab/api/v3/projects/86/**merge_request**/323/merge (notice REQUEST, not REQUESTS)

Comment: In GitLab 8.17.2 both singular `merge_request` and plural `merge_requests` work.